How to Reject an Action Goal
when the goal_callback function in the Action Server returns GoalResponse.REJECT, instead of GoalResponse.ACCEPT, the Action Client hangs. How I can make client also gives rejection response to me?

Have a look at the actions example.
More specifically, the server rejection logic is here and the client handles the rejection here.
If your implementation is similar but does not work, post a minimal code example that shows the issue.
